# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir por atributo?

Tags: java, lista

Estoy haciendo una lista con menú de Recursos humanos y quiero mandar a imprimir por departamento, es decir, que el programa sólo me muestre las personas de un departamento específico como por ejemplo gerencia o producción.
esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora.

```
   public String imprimirdep(String dep) {
   if(lvacia()){
        return "";
    }else{
        String dep1="La lista por departamento es ";
        nodo aux=raiz;
        for (int i = 1; i < tam; i++) {
            if(aux.mdepartamento().equals(dep)){
           dep1+=aux.mdepartamento()+"\n"; 
       }
          aux=aux.msig();
   }        
   return dep1;              
   }
}
```

y al mandar a imprimir en mi menú sólo me pide que ingrese el departamento a imprimir, sin embargo no imprime nada.

ayuda por favor, soy nueva en programación.

Comment: Hola. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el código como texto, no como imagen. Basta con copiar/pegar. Mucho más sencillo y mejor para analizar viendo el código como texto.

Comment: Hola Valeria. El problema con tu método es que de por sí no le estás diciendo que imprima nada. Te retorna un `String` pero no le dices que lo imprima. Tienes dos opciones (bueno, tienes muchas más pero dos son bastante directas). La primera es agregar antes del return un `System.out.println(dep1);`. La segunda opción es, donde sea que llames al método hacer el print, ejemplo: `System.out.println(obj.imprimirdep(dep))`.

Comment: Si, ya corregí eso en mi menú y ya salió, gracias :)